# SQL - Convert pipelined function to a java stored procedure/function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I've got the following types (A row type and a table of that kind of row):

```
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/
```

And the following pipelined function which returns information for that kind of table (for this example it just prints a basic iteration).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    PIPE ROW(t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i));
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
/
```

Instead of using a pipelined function with its definition like above, I want to use a java stored procedure that does the exact same thing. How can I achieve the same output from this?

I want to be able to call the java stored procedure/function just like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(get_tab_ptf(10))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Thanks

PS: This question is meant for learning purposes only.

Comment: Why do you want to make this change - what's wrong with a pipelined function? And how far have you got with your JSP? It seems like it'll be a much more complicated process than you have now (assuming it's possible at all; I'm not entirely sure...)

Comment: This one above is just an example that I want to test in order to make sure that it is possible. The real final use is that I want to make a connection to another database (DB2) through ODCI implemented in a JSP and display some columns (instead of pipelined function ODCI conn). I am not sure either if it is possible, I could not even make the proper JSP for the example above.

Comment: There is **no benefit** to converting this PL/SQL function to a Java stored procedure. It is really not clear how you think that a Java stored procedure will solve your actual problem either. I think if you tried to articulate what difference you expect to see in a database function written in Java versus a database procedure written in PL/SQL you would realise that too. So perhaps you should rewrite this question to present **the actual problem you want to solve** and let us try to solve that for you.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to make a JSP that connects to DB2 without a database link connected to a listener because there remain orphan sessions from the connection pool. But that is not the question in here, I just need to understand HOW a very generic JSP works for a pipelined result (like the one in question above). The rest from there I'm trying to figure out myself (the "real" problem that I will be solving will be more complex). This question is for learning purposes only.